# React Autocomplete - Why is "required" not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im following exactly what other examples have shown, but "required" is not working. Am I missing something?

```
                <Autocomplete
                    id="exp-projects"
                    data-testid="select-projects"
                    options={projectOptions}
                    style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}
                    value={projects}
                    filterOptions={filterOptions}
                    getOptionLabel={({ name }) => name}
                    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                        value.id === option.id
                    }
                    onChange={(event, newValue) => setProjects(newValue)}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            inputProps={{
                                ...params.inputProps,
                                required: projects.length === 0,
                            }}
                            data-testid="field-projects"
                            label="Projects"
                            required
                        />
                    )}
                    multiple
                />
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: @Pointy When I dont fill out the field, it lets me proceed without filling the field out.

Comment: The HTML "required" attribute only takes effect at form submission time

Comment: @Pointy yeah, thats where im seeing the issue. Its letting me proceed with the submission when there is nothing in the input

Comment: Well you should probably look at what the form actually looks like on the page. The browser doesn't know anything about React; all it knows is what's in the form elements.

Comment: The `required` attribute works for the _native HTML_ form submission process. You're using React, so the odds that your form is a normal HTML form, without its submit functionality intercepted and handled by React on the JS side are approximately zero. As such: which form handling library are you using, and what do its docs say about marking fields as required?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good question. I dont actually know. Im digging thru a project right now, really new to react. This whole page is just wrapped in a Container, with nothing about a form library specified

Its basically just a card with multiple input sections. First few having `required` that works correctly, but those are in `TextFields`. But with the `Autocomplete`, no luck